# IQueryable does not contain a definition for 'Select'

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, iqueryable

I'm trying to create a method that will take in a `Func<Object1, bool>` as a where clause and perform a Select on it as a subquery. This seems to be causing an error on the `IQueryable` where it cannot cast it to an expression to be parsed.

```
using System.Linq
using System.Data.Entity;

public IEnumerable<Object2> CreateObject2List<T> (Expression<Func<T, Object1> whereClause) 
{
    var parentQuery = (from r in dataSet.SomeObject
                       select new Object1 { Value1 = r.value1, Value2 = r.Value2 }

    var subQuery = parentQuery.Where(whereClause)
                   .Select<Object1, Object2>( o => new Object2{
        Value3 = Value1 + Value2,
        Value4 = Value1 - Value2
    })

    return subQuery.ToList();
}
```

The problem is occurring on the subQuery. It states:

> 'IQueryable' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and the best
>   extension method overload `'Queryable.Select<Object1, Object2>
>   (IQueryable<Object1>, Expression<Func<Object1, Object2>>)'` requires a
>   receiver of type 'IQueryable'.

I don't understand how it's not able to recognize that I've already provided an expression in the form of the lambda on the subquery. I made sure that I am using both System.Linq and System.Data.Entity. The delegate type that it is asking for is already there, so why can it not compile?

Also, for clarity, I am doing this because there are other sub-queries to be performed later, this is not a 1-to-1 snippet. I'm going for extensibility on the method call as a service.

Any help would be appreciated, and I can provide more detail as needed, thank you!

Comment: remove the generic arguments `<Object1, Object2>` and just call `Select` let the call infer the type based on the collection and returned type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most likely need

```
Expression<Func<Object1, bool>>
```

And replace `.Select<Object1, Object2>(` with `.Select(`, as mentioned in comments

Comment: Thank you! It seems like making the Expression use a strongly-typed in parameter did the trick.